# Can't find Error in mySQL query error 1005

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am new to PHP and mySQL, I cant seem to know wher the error is, the query is

delimiter $$

```
CREATE TABLE `bms`.`client_unit_people` (
  `unit_people_ID` int(13) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_block_ID` int(13) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `client_unit_ID` int(13) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `people_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `people_salutation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `people_telephone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `people_mobile` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_account_ID` int(13) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `web_access` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `tel_prefs` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `mob_prefs` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `email_prefs` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  PRIMARY KEY (`unit_people_ID`),
  KEY `FK_up_ua_idx` (`user_account_ID`),
  KEY `FK_ua_up_idx` (`user_account_ID`),
  KEY `FK_up_cu_idx` (`client_unit_ID`),
  KEY `FK_up_cb_idx` (`client_block_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_up_cb` FOREIGN KEY (`client_block_ID`) REFERENCES `client_blocks` (`client_block_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ua_up` FOREIGN KEY (`user_account_ID`) REFERENCES `user_accounts` (`user_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_up_cu` FOREIGN KEY (`client_unit_ID`) REFERENCES `client_units` (`client_unit_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='List of people associated with units'$$
```

The error i am receiving is:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'bms.client_unit_people' (errno: 150)

Comment: can you also post the structure of `client_blocks`, `user_accounts`, and `client_units`

Comment: check the column types and if they are signed or unsigned in the referenced tables

Comment: that worked, only user_account_ID foreign key original was signed,

Comment: Check field types maybe a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. Or  maybe the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table

Answer (score 1):

I think the foreign key constraints have to reference indexed columns in the target table, of the correct type.

Ensure you've created indexes in those table for the relevant keys and that the types match.

For example, `client_blocks` should have an index on `client_block_ID`, and the types between the two tables should be identical.

The [online documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) shows that this is the most likely cause for 1005/150 errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are re-creating a table which was dropped earlier, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. Normally 150 error is with respect to the foreign key constraint. The column names and types need to be proper and indexes as to be there for referenced keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find a hint for your problem in [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,19755) thread from the MySQL forums. Hope that helps :)